# Why does != not work , when the function should not let other text

Tags: python

I made a simple root and squared calculator , and If I type anything that is not R or P or r or p it shouldn't let you , but it does. Can someone help me?

The code is below :

````
while a == 1:
    question = input("R pentru radical , P pentru patrat perfect : ")
    if question in("R", "r"):
        number = int(input("Zi un numar : "))
        sqrt = number ** 0.5
        print("Radical:", sqrt)
    elif question in("p" or "p"):
        patrat = int(input("Zi un numar : "))
        outpatrat = patrat ** 2
        print("Patrat perfect:", outpatrat)
    else :
        print("Cuvant incorect!")

    time.sleep(1)

    answer = input("Apasa Y pentru a folosi din nou programul , N pentru a iesi : ") 
    if answer == "Y" :
        a == 1
    elif answer != "Y" or "N":
        exit()
    elif answer == "N": 
        exit()  ```
````

Comment: `if question == "R" or "r":` is always true - you compare question agains "R" and look if "r" is truthy (which it is, because it is a non empty string). Use `if question in "Rr":` or `if question.lower() == "r":` or `if question in ("R","r"):` etc.

Comment: and change `elif question != "R" or "P" or "r" or "p":` to simple "else:"

Comment: I changed it to else, it still doesn't work

Comment: And after it says "Cuvant incorect!" it should redo the cycle , not start with "Apasa Y".How can I do that?

Comment: Look for a python tutorial of your choice and use loops. `while` loop should work

Comment: but i always have a while loop. i edited it now the code

Comment: use `while True:` and `break` if needed - no need to modify `a`

Comment: and you STILL have `elif answer != "Y" or "N":` - wich is **always** True

Comment: I modified it , but where should I put while true , i dont understand, i'm a beginner at python